# Destroying a session in node on a specific event

Tags: node.js, session, express

Basically, my app receives a request from the platform hosting it saying that my app was uninstalled by a specific user. In this request I want to log the user out by destroying `req.session` , but since the request is not from the actual user I don't have access to that session. Is there anyway to destroy their session?

Comment: A user in your system must have some identifying information (email or user ID usually).  You would need to use that to find the session that corresponds with that user.

Comment: Thanks! I can get the user by id or name, but how would you get the session from here? Its attached to the req object no?

Comment: It depends entirely upon what session infrastructure you are using in your server.  The session info is stored somewhere in your server (in a Javascript object or in a database).  You would look up and find that user's unique identifier in the session store and remove the corresponding session from the store.  No request needed.  How you do that depends upon what you're using for storing sessions and what information is stored there which your question include no info about so all we can do is speak in generalities.

Comment: FYI, questions about code are nearly always more likely to generate good answers if you show us the code you're already using.  In this case, we'd need to see what session infrastructure you're using, how your login works that creates a session and see what the data is you get from your platform asking you to remove a user.  Specifics are good for stimulating good answers.